# How do I use Stata in org-mode with spacemacs

Tags: emacs, stata, org-mode, spacemacs

I have been a loyal user of emacs. Recently, I switched to using spacemacs and enjoy it very much. For a while, I was able to use Stata in org-mode in spacemacs through ESS. After a recent update, I cannot use Stata in org-mode anymore because Stata is obsolete the latest release of ESS. When I try to edit the following code block,

```
#+begin_src stata :tangle yes
 webuse auto;
#+end_src
```

I cannot open the clock block and get an error message as follows

```
org-edit-src-code: No such language mode: stata-mode
```

I am using the develop branch of spacemacs 0.300 with emacs 27.0.50. And, I output my system information using

```
uname -a
```

with the following output

```
Linux 4.15.0-112-generic #113~16.04.1-Ubuntu x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I do not think I can use any layer other than ESS in spacemacs to solve this problem. How do I use Stata in org-mode with spacemacs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I temporarily solve this problem by downgrading ESS to an earlier version, and it works for now. I take steps as follows.

1. Remove the ess layer from dotspacemacs-configuration-layers of .spacemacs
2. Add the following into dotspacemacs-additional-packages of .spacemacs
   (ess :location (recipe :fetcher git :url "https://github.com/emacs-ess/ESS.git" :commit "14b9a3091916a1cb74dec7336e8461590dfc6a7d" :files ("lisp/*.el" "contrib/lisp/*.el" "doc/dir" "doc/*.texi" "etc")))
3. Then restart spacemacs (SPC q r).

[#7071](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/7071) and [#6575](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/pull/6575) are helpful references